# I would like to use VBA to create a function using data from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I am trying to simplify a formula on excel by creating a VBA function. I would like the function to work as shown in here.

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste images of code: copy the code from the VB editor and paste it into your question.  Select it and use the `{}` button to format it.  Is there a problem with your posted code?  If Yes, what is it?

Comment: (1) Your function name is mis-typed as `TypeDes` (2) Your lookup table is only A10:D15 but in your VBA you're accessing a value from Column G ?  (3)  `TypeDesc = IIf(YN = "Yes", Qty, 0)` with no quotes around `Qty`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind for my next question and I will copy the code instead. For points (1) and (2) I believe I created those typos whilst trying to rename and simplify the spreadsheet I was working on to make it easier to explain what I needed and ask the question, my original table located in the "data" sheet was 3 columns wider hence the error you mention in (2). Thanks for (3) that was a genuine mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Function TypeDesc(Desc As String, Qty As Double) As Double
    Dim m
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").ListObjects("Types15")
        'vlookup works well here...
        m = Application.VLookup(Desc, .DataBodyRange, 4, False) 'you have 7 here?
    End With
    If IsError(m) Then m = "No" 'error means no match: set to "No"
    TypeDesc = IIf(m = "Yes", Qty, 0)
End Function
```